# Draw histogram from points array

Tags: c#, histogram

I am working on an image processing project.

I want to draw an histogram for an image. I get red color from an image but i don't know how to draw it as an histogram so I need your help.

This is my code:

```
class MainClass
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("F://DSC_0242.jpg");
        int[] histogram_r = new int[255];
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
            {
                histogram_r[bmp.GetPixel(i,j).R]++;
                if (max < histogram_r[bmp.GetPixel(i,j).R])
                    max = histogram_r[bmp.GetPixel(i,j).R];
            }
        }

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(256, max + 10);
        Point[] points = new Point[256];

        for (int i = 0; i < histogram_r.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new Point(i, img.Height-(histogram_r.Length/100));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tagged this as [tag:c++]; feel free to update the tags if I guessed incorrectly.

Comment: @tripleee `public static void main(string[] args)` is not C++ code.

Comment: @remyabel Close but no cigar. ;-)

Comment: @Konrad Whoops, I didn't look closely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to declare your histogram array with a size of 256, not 255.  I made some generic cleanup in the code below but things relevant to your question are as follows...

- You can use the Graphics class to write directly to your output image
- To determine how high each line in the histogram should be, first figure out what percentage of the max you are dealing with.  Then draw a line that is that percentage of the desired output size.
- The code below creates an output image 10 pixels higher than what is specified in histHeight.  Each line in the histogram starts 5 pixels from the bottom giving a 5 pixel border on the top and bottom.

I used one of the sample files included in Win7 so you'll have to change it to your pic.  I'm also outputting the histogram to the temp folder, so do whatever you need to there as well.

```
        private void Test()
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
            int[] histogram_r = new int[256];
            float max = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
                {
                    int redValue = bmp.GetPixel(i, j).R;
                    histogram_r[redValue]++;
                    if (max < histogram_r[redValue])
                        max = histogram_r[redValue];
                }
            }

            int histHeight = 128;
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(256, histHeight + 10);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < histogram_r.Length; i++)
                {
                    float pct = histogram_r[i] / max;   // What percentage of the max is this value?
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black,
                        new Point(i, img.Height - 5),
                        new Point(i, img.Height - 5 - (int)(pct * histHeight))  // Use that percentage of the height
                        );
                }
            }
            img.Save(@"c:\temp\test.jpg");
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: @Hamodea - Did this work for you?  If so, please accept, otherwise please post your results so that the others can assist.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for making a answer, I don't have enough reputation to add comment to an existing answer.

@dazedandconfused's answer is 99.9% correct. I'd only add a cast to float when getting the "pct" as the unit percentage.

Basically:

```
float pct = (float)histogram_r[i] / max;
```

I've skimmed down the method to just draw the histogram with a big of gap for better view:

```
public void DrawHistogram(int[] histogram)
{
    var histogramHeight = 256;
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(1024, histogramHeight);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
        {
            float unit = (float)histogram[i] / histogram.Max();

            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black,
                new Point(i * 4, histogramHeight - 5),
                new Point(i * 4, histogramHeight - 5 - (int)(unit * histogramHeight)));
        }
    }

    bitmap.Save(filename: @"C:\test\result.jpg");
}
```